# How to mask console input and still out put to the console : C++11

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, console-application, password-protection

I'm working on a console application where the user inputs a password. Naturally I want to mask it by showing *'s instead of their input. So this is the function I have made. But all it does is hide the echo all together. It only shows the *'s after I reset the console mode. Any help is appreciated. Code:

```
void mask(std::string &s)
{
    char c;
    s.clear();

    HANDLE hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD mode = 0;
    GetConsoleMode(hStdin, &mode);
    SetConsoleMode(hStdin, mode & (~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT));

    c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n')
    {
        s.push_back(c);
        std::cout << "*";
        c = getchar();
    }

    SetConsoleMode(hStdin, mode);
}
```

P.S. I am running windows 10 and my IDE is 2017 Visual studios community edition.

Comment: You need to clear the `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` flag instead, which also implicitly disables `ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT`. Otherwise reading from the console won't return until it reads a carriage return (`'\r'`).

Comment: This will work best with `ReadConsoleW` and `std::wstring`, which allows reading any Unicode character. In this case the character to break on is `L'\r'`, since you're not using the CRT's text-mode newline translation. Also, at startup you can make the CRT use UTF-16 for stdout via `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)`. Then you can write Unicode to the console via `std::wcout`.

Comment: Hey thank you! I will begin testing with this asap.