# How to take input in the form of Asterisk (*) in C rather than showing the input (in the terminal [WINDOWS])?

Tags: c, windows, terminal, user-input

I want to create a program in `C` which will take the input (in terminal) but don't show it on the terminal in direct form, rather it will show the input in the form of Asterisks (****), as if we are entering a password.

I haven't written anything yet because I don't even have an idea that how to start!

Can you tell me how to write its code and what's the logic we should apply if there is no inbuilt function for it (or no headers)?

Sample:

```
Enter a string : this is string
```

It should be taken as

```
Enter a string : **************
```

Comment: [How to mask console input and still out put to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49167646/995714), [how to get a password input in c++ console application (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13687769/995714), [Masking the user input as asterisks in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58571242/995714)

Comment: @kaylum that question is about Linux

Comment: @phuclv True, I missed seeing the Linux tag. Though it does have a Windows answer in there anyway.